# How to make a SwiftUI .sheet() size match the width/height of window on MacOS?

Tags: swiftui

**Background**

I am working on a MacOS application in SwiftUI in Xcode 12.4 on Catalina. Right now my app has a landing page with tiles and each tile contains a feature that is displayed using sheets.

```
ForEach(MenuItem.allCases) { menuItem in
    Button(action: {
        detailView = menuItem
    }) {
        Tile(labelText: menuItem.menuText, icon: menuItem.menuIcon)
            .sheet(item: $detailView) { item in
                FeatureView(dismissFeatureView: { self.detailView = nil }, menuItem: item)
                    .environmentObject(container)
                    .background(Color("backgroundMain"))
            }
    }
}
```

The window has a minimum width and height, but can be expanded given it has no max height or width. I'm looking for a way to make the sheet take up the entire screen. On iOS you can use `.fullScreenCover()` but this isn't available on MacOS. So now, when I make the screen large and click on a tile [the sheet view doesn't take up the entire space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzRKe.png).

Additionally, the user is able to resize the sheet beyond the size of the window, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxFBv.png).

**The Question**

How can I get the sheet views to match the size of the window (which does not have a max width or height) so the user can still resize the window, but ensure that the sheet always takes up the entirety of the window.

Answer (score 5):

If you're displaying a sheet after a user interaction, you can set the sheet content's frame like this:

```
.frame(idealWidth: NSApp.keyWindow?.contentView?.bounds.width ?? 500, idealHeight: NSApp.keyWindow?.contentView?.bounds.height ?? 500)
```

The neat part is that this can be used by nested controls that don't know anything about their superviews.

`500` is used as a fallback width/height if a [`keyWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428406-keywindow) can't be found.

Keep in mind: The sheet may be taller than the height of its content's frame, because it may contain additional controls (e.g. a toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `GeometryReader` to obtain the size of the parent view, and apply that to the frame of the sheet. See code below:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(MenuItem.allCases) { menuItem in
                Button(action: {
                    detailView = menuItem
                }) {
                    Tile(labelText: menuItem.menuText, icon: menuItem.menuIcon)
                        .sheet(item: $detailView) { item in
                            FeatureView(dismissFeatureView: { self.detailView = nil }, menuItem: item)
                                .environmentObject(container)
                                .background(Color("backgroundMain"))
                                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```